# In Sinatra, how to render json?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I find it very weird that this is OK:

```
  get '/initialize' do
    # ok 
    json foo: 'bar'
  end
```

Yet this causes an error:

```
  get '/initialize' do
    json { foo: 'bar' }   # error! 
  end
```

> syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' (SyntaxError)

Why?

How can I write the code like :

```
  get '/initialize' do
    json { 
         item1: { 
             item2: {
                 item3: 'ok'
             }
         } 
    }

  end
```

Comment: Which version of ruby you're using?

Comment: my ruby version is  2.3.8

Comment: fyi .. there is sinatra contrib with json example - http://sinatrarb.com/contrib/json.html .. the syntax is `json :foo => bar`

Comment: `json` is a `sinatra-contrib` method, therefore this is a question related to `sinatra-contrib` rather than `sinatra`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the latter case assumes you're calling `json` method with a block, and `foo: 'bar'` is an invalid statement. I.e.

```
json { foo: 'bar' }
```

is parsed in (almost) the same way as

```
json do
  foo: 'bar'
end
```

which is nonsense. ("almost" because the priority of braces and `do...end` differ a bit; not that it matters in this case.)

The former case assumes `foo: 'bar'` is a named argument, and is converted into a `Hash`. `json({ foo: 'bar' })` would make it explicit that you're passing a `Hash`, and not writing a block. Thus, the following is the correct syntax for what you are trying to write:

```
get '/initialize' do
  json({ 
       item1: { 
           item2: {
               item3: 'ok'
           }
       } 
  })
end
```

You can also use the keyword approach (though I find it's less readable):

```
get '/initialize' do
  json item1: { 
           item2: {
               item3: 'ok'
           }
       }
end
```

Comment: OK, thanks a lot! for me, I would prefer the Rails way. I really don't want to write the out most "(" and ")".   :-)

Comment: You may want to try `json(...)` to make it clear it's not a block. As in: `json(item1: { ... }, ...)` where the first layer of `{ .... }` braces can be omitted.

Answer (score 6):

It works for me:

```
get '/songs' do
    content_type :json
    { song: "Wake me Up" }.to_json
end
```

Comment: that `content_type :json` is exactly what I was looking for, combines well with `JSON.pretty_print(hash)`